# How to compare two columns of IP and hostnames grepped from multiple files in bash

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to grep IPs from a number of files, look them up in DNS and compare them to the hostnames already in the same files to ensure both are correct. Then print out anything that is wrong.

I've gathered I need to put the information into arrays and diff them somehow.

Here is my horrible bash code which does not work. I'm pretty sure at least my for loop is wrong:

```
declare -a ipaddr=(`grep -h address *test.com.cfg | awk '{print $2}'`)
declare -a host_names=(`grep -h address *test.com.cfg | awk '{print $2}'`)

for i in "${ipaddr[@]}"
do
lookedup_host_names=( $(/usr/sbin/host ${ipaddr[@]} | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d. -f1-4 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'))
done
if [[ -z diff <(printf "%s\n" "${lookedup_host_names[@]}"| sort ) <(printf "%s\n" "${host_names[@]}"| sort) ]]
then
printf "%s\n" "${lookedup_host_names[@]}"
fi
```

Comment: There are several caveats to consider.

Reverse host lookup may return a hostname but the file may contain the CNAME.

Forward lookup will return all CNAMEs instead of just IP Address.

The easiest is to use `gethostip` using `-d` option to return the IP address regardless of CNAMEs.

The only caveat in this one is multiple IPs. DNS names with multiple IP addresses will only return one IP address when `gethstip -d` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two principal problems are that your for loop overwrites the array each time rather than appending, and your diff check is invalid.

To quickly fix the for loop, you could use `+=` instead of `=`, .e.g `lookedup_host_names+=( ... )`.

To do the diff, you don't really need a condition. You could just run

```
diff <(printf "%s\n" "${host_names[@]}"| sort ) <(printf "%s\n" "${lookedup_host_names[@]}"| sort)
```

and it would show any differences between the two in diff format which most Unix users are familiar with (note that I switched the arguments around, since the first argument is supposed to be original).

If, like in your example, you actually do want to compare them and show the entire final list if there is a difference, you could do

```
if diff <(printf "%s\n" "${host_names[@]}"| sort ) <(printf "%s\n" "${lookedup_host_names[@]}"| sort) > /dev/null
then
    printf "%s\n" "${lookedup_host_names[@]}"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, the += put me on the right track, here is the final script:

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a difference between your arrays ipaddr and host_names. Supposed your files contain lines like

```
address 1.2.3.4 somehost.tld
```

a script like this may do what you want.

```
cat *test.com.cfg | grep address | while read line; do  
    IP=$(awk {'print $2'}); 
    CO=$(awk {'print $3'}); 
    CN=$(host $CO | cut -d ' ' -f 4)
    [ "$CN" = "$IP" ] || echo "Error with IP $IP"; 
done
```